# Creating a working search bar while hiding the list to search from

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a working search bar for my HTML/CSS/JS project. What I want to do is hide the list with the search options, but still be able to search things there. I am using a template from W3 schools. Here is the code.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myUL {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
  padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
  color: black; /* Add a black text color */
  display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I.E, I want to hide the names, but still be able to search them up.
If someone could help me with this, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the includes() method to find a string that contains your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need this?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && filter != "") {//change here
            li[i].style.display = "";
            li[i].style.visibility = "visible";//change here
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myUL {
  /* Remove default list styling */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
  padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
  font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
  color: black; /* Add a black text color */
  display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL" style="visibility: hidden">//change here
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css

```
#myUL li {
  display: none;
}
```

And change js function

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you can explain your answer.

Comment: I make all `li` `display: none;` by default. In function i only changet string `li[i].style.display = "";` on `li[i].style.display = "block";`. So that the value equates not to emptiness, but to a block.